# How to keep helm value file up to date in gitlab ci pipeline?

Tags: deployment, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I have two different repos for backend and frontend. These repos have pipelines that build and push docker images with new version tags. After pushing new images they trigger a deploy pipeline in a different repo that has a helm value file and pass the version tag as a variable which is then used in the command line to deploy the new version like this:

```
helm upgrade my-app ./my-chart -n staging -f values.yaml --set frontend.version=$FRONTEND_TAG
```

But the new frontend version is not saved so when the backend repo triggers deployment it will redeploy the old version of frontend set in the values file.

Is there a way to keep the separate version values of frontend and backend up to date in the helm values file without updating it manually?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split into 2 different repos (backend and frontend)?
For frontend:

```
helm upgrade my-app ./my-chart-frontend -n staging -f values.yaml --set frontend.version=$FRONTEND_TAG
```

For backend:

```
helm upgrade my-app ./my-chart-backend -n staging -f values.yaml --set frontend.version=$BACKEND_TAG
```